# C++ Find object member value in Vector

Tags: c++, vector, struct, find

I have a Struct of Person which contains two values - first Initial and first Name.

There is a Vector of these Person Structs.

I need to search through the Vector to find the first person with the matching first initial and retrieve the first name from that Struct.

My research highlights the need to use an overloaded operator for the Person Struct but I require some guidance.

Note: Can only use a Vector and find() algorithm. Can't use Boost.

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <iostream>
  #include <stdexcept>
  #include <vector>
  #include <algorithm>
  #include <string>

  using namespace std;

  struct person
  {
     char firstInitial;
     string firstName;

     person(const char fi, const string fn)
     {
        firstInitial = fi;
        firstName = fn;
     };

     char getInitial()
     {
        return firstInitial;
     };

     string getName()
     {
        return firstName;
     };

     bool operator==(const person& l, const person& r) const
     {
        return l.firstInitial == r.firstInitial;
     }

  };


  int main (int argc, char *argv[])
  {
     vector<person> myvector;
     vector<person>::iterator itr;

     myvector.push_back(person('j', "john"));
     myvector.push_back(person('s', "steve"));
     myvector.push_back(person('c', "candice"));

     itr = find (myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), itr->getInitial() == 's');

     if (itr != myvector.end())
        cout << "First Name: " << itr->getName() << '\n';
     else
        cout << "NOT Found" << '\n';
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.`operator==()` should be a binary function. If you want it to be a member function, it should take one parameter, like:

```
bool operator==(const person& r) const
{
    return firstInitial == r.firstInitial;
}
```

or make it a non-member function (move it out of the class declaration):

```
bool operator==(const person& l, const person& r)
{
    return l.firstInitial == r.firstInitial;
}
```

2.[`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) expects its 3rd argument to be the value to be compared to, you could change it to:

```
itr = find (myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), person('s', ""));
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/YWF45230)

Answer (score 0):

The `operator==` member function takes only one parameter, not two. Its job is to compare `this` with another instance of the class, that's passed as the single parameter.

Additionally, `std::find`'s third parameter is not a boolean value, but an instance of an object to find in the sequence to be searched. Alternatively, a lambda can be supplied as a third parameter to `std::find_if`.